# htaccess: How can I hide parts of the link?

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to hide parts of the link using .htaccess rewrite rule?
I'm working on hotlink protection. The playlist is generated with the following link: `http://site.com/get.playlist.php?`

the full link:

```
http://site.com/get.playlist.php?playlist=http://site.com/video/34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69/pl/playlist.txt&hash=34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69
```

i would like to display the link without `&hash=` and `http://site.com/get.playlist.php?playlist=`

like this:

```
http://site.com/video/34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69/pl/playlist.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just prevent that link any other hotlink prevention? 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://hpmouse.googlepages.com/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible (at least, not in any rational manner) using `.htaccess`.

There's no way to change the URL that the browser is displaying- however, you *could* do the opposite- `.htaccess` does have the power to keep the URL the same, but display a different page on the server.

This would be a bit harder to setup (especially because of the `hash` parameter), but may be something for you to consider.

Comment: I see, so what rule would i write to to keep the URL the same, but display a different page on the server?

Comment: opened as different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544765/htaccess-how-can-i-keep-the-same-the-url-but-display-a-different-page-on-the