# .htaccess: How can I keep the same the URL, but display a different page on the server

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, nginx

How can I keep the same the URL, but display a different page on the server using .htaccess rewrite rule?
I'm working on hotlink protection. The playlist is generated with the following link: `http://site.com/get.playlist.php?`

the full link:

```
http://site-1.com/get.playlist.php?playlist=http://site.com/video/34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69/pl/playlist.txt&hash=34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69
```

i would like to redirect the link from

```
http://site-2.com/video/34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69/pl/playlist.txt
```

to

```
http://site-1.com/get.playlist.php?playlist=http://site.com/video/34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69/pl/playlist.txt&hash=34141ce7760f58f0c3eb5e0c758afb69
```

Comment: You think you get more results by asking the same question again?

Comment: i flagged the previous question to be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^video/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ http://site-1.com/get.playlist.php?playlist=http://site.com/video/$1/$2/$3&hash=$1
```

Although that would probably result in an invalid url, you would need to url encode the characters like `:` and `/` in the query string.

An additional problem is that the redirect is to a different domain, so the url would probably change in the browser address bar.

Is it really on a different domain, as your question title seems to imply otherwise?

If not, you can change it to:

```
 RewriteRule ^video/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ /get.playlist.php?playlist=http://site.com/video/$1/$2/$3&hash=$1
```

Comment: I think it might be time for modrewrite.stackexchange.com.